# What type of cookie to use, when an Australian recipe calls for "crushed biscuits"?

Tags: substitutions

I have a recipe from my teenage years in Australia for a bar cookie called "Cherry Crunch". It includes cashews, arrowroot, cocoa and "biscuits", among other things. I know that biscuits are cookies, but have no idea what type of cookie to use. I'm assuming it would be something rather plain?

Comment: I would guess something along the lines of s digestive

Answer (score 2):

As an Australian we seem to use Arnott's Milk Arrowroot or Arnott's Milk Coffee biscuits in a lot of recipes.

[Milk Arrowroot](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTEaYFn9kGbl4hG0cMlB9EfTR8znWSgOkitRO70zlB04I05HdFiHg)

Answer (score 0):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobnob_biscuit

I think a cookie like a hobnob would work. I put a link above if you aren't familiar with this brand. I think they would work beautifully. Otherwise I think any nice crunchy oatmeal cookie 
would be yummy.